# Is it possible to block specific mail accounts on iOS in a third-party app?

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I am thinking about creating a very simple iOS app that depending on what you select inside the app would block specific mail accounts in your Mail app on your iOS device. For example, you could select to block your work email address in the evening, so it does not pull in mail when you open the Mail app. There is a bit more too it, but essentially what I am trying to determine is if it is possible to a) generally — alter default iOS apps via third-party apps and b) specifically — block specific mail accounts from pulling in mail using a third party app. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) It's not possible with a "regular" app. You'll need to write an app for jailbroken devices (not much documentation on that though, good luck lol).

b) Once you start on a jailbreak app project, I think pretty much everything is possible. You can alter the system apps and do what almost anything you want (as long as you know how to do it).

There may be another way, which would be to create a full mail replacement app, where you offer all the basic functionalities and more. Maybe not a *sexy* as your idea, but it might be easier than a jailbreak app.

Comment: That is what I thought unfortunately. Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide any method of accessing the Mail app in the method you're attempting to do.

Remember as a first party app the Mail client **always** runs in a background process.  Even if Apple provided an API to do what you're trying to do your app would have to follow the normal background task limitation of third party apps, meaning it would shut down eventually, leaving the Mail client to send mail unaffected by your filtering.